# Set release mode (Java boolean variable) in Jenkins

Tags: android, build-process, build-automation, jenkins, release-management

We are using Jenkins to make our builds. 
We would like to switch boolean value in release build. 
Is it possible?
Maybe it's better option to do this?

In C you could just define a value by passing -D and you call
`gcc -DUSE_ASD=1 asd.c`

```
#ifdef USE_ASD
int debug = 0;
#else
int debug = 1;
#endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem anymore. With update of `Android` platform tools this type of flag was added.

Answer (score 0):

You don't generally do this sort of thing in Java. You would more usually do something like establish a system property to control debug state.

```
static final boolean DEBUG = !Boolean.valueOf(System.getProperty("use.asd"));
```

And then set it on the command line when running Jenkins; I don't know the details of how to edit Jenkins's runtime but it amounts to adding `-Duse.asd=true` to the `java` command.

Comment: But in Java You pass it runtime whereas in C it is set during compile time. Additionally we can't pass those arguments to JVM since we are using Dalvik VM and Android application package file (APK).

Comment: Yeah that's indeed a difference. There isn't a preprocessor in Java, really. You could use an Ant task to copy a template .java file, replacing some token with a true or false, and then compile -- faking a preprocessor with an Ant copy task?

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can ask the compiler to generate debug tables using the `-g` option. For a release you might actually want a `-g:none`. This can be controlled either -

- Using the command line : http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html
- Using ANT and providing the `debug` or `debuglevel` task options. http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html
- Using Maven and providing similar compiler options. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html